# Python Pandas Data Frame - Optimization search data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I recently started writing code. It turns out that so far it is not very good in terms of code optimization. I will be glad to receive good advice from you.

I wrote a function that takes a list of parameters, searches for data in the Data Frame and returns a list of values if the value is one; returns a number if there are several values; and returns None if the value is not found according to the criteria. The search for the value takes place in several stages. First, the search takes place with the criteria in two columns. If the value is not found, but the search is performed by the criteria for one column.

The code runs for a very long time and processes about 10,000 values per hour.

Please tell me what I need to pay attention to when optimizing the code

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

Source data:

```
list_fields = ['MDR', 'MDR STATUS', 'CERTIFICATION AND TP MATRIX',
                       'CERTIFICATION AND TP MATRIX STATUS', 'MDRB', 'MDRB STATUS']
        list_criteria = ['A01', 'Status A01', 'K43',
                         'Status K43', 'K30', 'Status K30']
        df_final[list_fields] = [document_reference(
            row, df_vdb, list_criteria) for index, row in df_etd.iterrows()]
```

Result:

> ['3000-KTSS07100001-A01-00001-00',    '2',    '3000-KTSS07100001-K43-00001-00',   R, '3000-KTSS07100001-K30-00071-00',    '2']

```
def document_reference(df, df1, criteria):
    result_list = []
    po = df['Requisition number'].replace(
        '-MR-', '-PO-') + '-' + df['PO Number'].replace('GYG', '')
    po = po.replace('_', '')
    try:
        tag = re.search('\d*-\D*-\d*', df['Tag Number']).group()
    except:
        tag = df['Tag Number']
    for item in criteria:
        if 'Status' not in item:
            result = df1[['document_reference', 'current_status']].loc[(df1['purchase_order_reference'] == po) &
                                                                       (df1['document_reference'].str.find(item) != -1) &
                                                                       (df1['document_title'].str.find(tag) != -1)].drop_duplicates(subset=['document_reference'])
            if result.shape[0] > 1:
                result_list.extend([result.shape[0], None])
            elif result.shape[0] == 1:
                result_list.extend(
                    [result['document_reference'].all(), result['current_status'].all()])
            else:
                result = df1[['document_reference', 'current_status']].loc[(df1['purchase_order_reference'] == po) &
                                                                           (df1['document_reference'].str.find(item) != -1)].drop_duplicates(subset=['document_reference'])
                if result.shape[0] > 1:
                    result_list.extend([result.shape[0], None])
                elif result.shape[0] == 1:
                    result_list.extend(
                        [result['document_reference'].all(), result['current_status'].all()])
                else:
                    result_list.extend([None, None])
    # print(result_list)
    return result_list
```

Comment: Could you also provide snippets of the source and target outcome? Thanks!

Comment: Added to description

Comment: Can you post samples of `df_vdb`, `df_etd` and `df_final` so we can run your code?

Comment: df_etd and df_vdb are DataFrame from excel file (pd.read_excel()). df_final and index no need for this function. I updated.